# Master-detail custom database update sequence using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, master-detail

I have 3 tables with the relationship as: CompanyStatus and Employee is the child table of Company, CompanyStatus and Employee is not link to each other.

When perform insert data using entity framework, by looking at the profiler, i notice that the update sequence of entity framework as below
1. Company
2. Employee
3. CompanyStatus

The problem is: i have an insert trigger in Employee table which check the CompanyStatus of the related Company and base on that perform some database update action. So when the new row has been inserted into Employee table, the CompanyStatus is not exists yet. How can i change the update data sequence of entity framework and make it insert data with the custom sequence like:
1. Company
2. CompanyStatus
3. Employee.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make CompanyStatus required for inserting a Company in your model, or SaveChanges() before adding the Employee.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your advise. Could you please show me how to make CompanyStatus required for inserting a Company model in entity framework ?

Comment: Add your model to your question.